# Is it possible to find what object an object belongs to?

Tags: java

```
class Entity {
  Coords coords, prevCoords;
  // Some more members and methods...
}

class Coords {
  Integer x = null, y = null;
  // More code...
}
```

I have a `Coords` object that belongs to an Entity object, but am not sure how to reference the `Entity`s member variables.

Comment: What do you need to referecne the Entity ? Share the Entity constuctor

Comment: The variable `coords` is just a reference to an object, thus the referenced object may "belong" to many different objects

Comment: No, an object doesn't know who is referencing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. In Object-oriented programming references (in Java all variables "containing" objects are references) are like arrows which point only one way. You can only walk from owning object to its owned objects.

Another way of thinking about it is to remember that one variable can only point to one object - but one object can be referenced by multiple variables. In your case, there could be code that puts the same coords object in multiple entities. This shows that the notion of "owning entity" is meaningless.

In object-oriented programming, if you want to have two objects "knowing" about each other, you need to use two references: one in the "parent" and one in "child". And you need to write all the necessary code to keep them synchronized (i.e. each piece of code that changes parent should also change the child). There's no sane way to do that automatic.

Two side notes:

1. in relational model, which is used in SQL databases, keys are bi-directional - very unlike the OO relations. This is a source of a very real problem and a root of complexity of Object-Relational mappers.
2. I vaguely remember that an obscure, old language called "A-Code", HAD bi-directional relations. However, I don't remember where I got this piece of information and cannot easily find confirmation right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner class to achieve this:

```
class Entity {
  Coords coords, prevCoords;
  // Some more members and methods...

  String name;

  class Coords {
    Integer x = null, y = null;
    // More code...
    public void doStuff() {
      //'name' is accessible here
      System.out.println(name);
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the Coords class knows about all of Entity's fields because the instance of Entity is available to the Coords class. The compiler has to do some trickery to get nested classes to work (like when accessing private members) but you yourself shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: "each instance of Entity has its own version of Coords" that's not true. They're all the same "version". `Coords` just a hidden reference to the enclosing instance of `Entity`.

Comment: Can the methods from the inner class etc. be accessed from elswhere, outside both classes?

Comment: @Gabriel They can be called like regular methods (as long as the access modifiers allow it)